# Get error when trying to get a value from a json

Tags: php

When I put the command `var_dump($values)` I have a Json below:

`{"data":[{"DT_RowId":"row_6","importa_sigtap":{"id":"6","rl_procedimento_ocupacao":"5","tb_procedimento":"4","tb_forma_organizacao":"6"}}]}`

I need to get the value from `tb_procedimento` but I put `var_dump($values['data'])` and return a error: `Warning: Illegal string offset 'data'`

How to get the value '4' from the 'tb_procedimento' key?

Note: the value `row_6` is a dynamic value and I can't know this.

Comment: Will there only ever be one value in the json?

Comment: @Mech yes, only one value with the keys `{"data":[{"DT_RowId":"row_6","importa_sigtap":{"id":"6","rl_procedimento_ocupacao":"5","tb_procedimento":"4","tb_forma_organizacao":"6"}}]}`

Comment: Do you [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it first?

Comment: @PaulT. I receive this Json from an application

Comment: Which is fine, we get JSON from many applications too, but you are indexing a string literal which is not a structure such as an array or object, and gives you the: `Illegal string offset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json = '{"data":[{"DT_RowId":"row_6","importa_sigtap":{"id":"6","rl_procedimento_ocupacao":"5","tb_procedimento":"4","tb_forma_organizacao":"6"}}]}';    /* your json */
$array = json_decode($json,true);

$wanted = $array[data][0][importa_sigtap][tb_procedimento];

echo $wanted;
```

json is an encoded string, json_decode converts it into php array

[manual](https://www.php.manual.net)